# JGit: How to use InMemoryRepository to learn about dfs implementations

Tags: daemon, jgit, microsoft-distributed-file-system

I want to learn how to implement an alternative dfs backend for jgit and am looking at
https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/blob/master/org.eclipse.jgit/src/org/eclipse/jgit/storage/dfs/InMemoryRepository.java
as an example.

How ever I am having a hard time figuring out how to set this up as a standalone git daemon.
Basically I want to be able to start a java process that is the git server for a single (empty) in-memory git repository, and then I want to be able to use a git client to push/pull from that repository daemon process.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do something like this:

```
private static final class RepositoryResolverImplementation implements
        RepositoryResolver<DaemonClient> {
    @Override
    public Repository open(DaemonClient client, String name)
            throws RepositoryNotFoundException,
            ServiceNotAuthorizedException, ServiceNotEnabledException,
            ServiceMayNotContinueException {
        InMemoryRepository repo = repositories.get(name);
        if (repo == null) {
            repo = new InMemoryRepository(
                    new DfsRepositoryDescription(name));
            repositories.put(name, repo);
        }
        return repo;
    }
}

private static Map<String, InMemoryRepository> repositories = new HashMap<String, InMemoryRepository>();

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Daemon server = new Daemon(new InetSocketAddress(9418));
    boolean uploadsEnabled = true;
    server.getService("git-receive-pack").setEnabled(uploadsEnabled);
    server.setRepositoryResolver(new RepositoryResolverImplementation());
    server.start();
}
```

You should then be able to run `git clone git://localhost/repo.git` and a new in-memory 'repo.git' repository will be created. If you want to upload, make sure that the uploadsEnabled is set to 'true' - by default, it is set to 'false'.