# Distributed file system as storage layer over git

Tags: git, repository, hbase, hdfs

Anyone who has tried Jgit's InMemoryRepository . Want to know how much it helps in performance ? I can say it improves disk performance, but don't have any idea about how it affects memory?   Any insights please.

Answer (score 1):

It affects memory in that the repo size will be stored in it.

And the own [`InMemoryRepository.java` documentation](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/blob/master/org.eclipse.jgit/src/org/eclipse/jgit/internal/storage/dfs/InMemoryRepository.java) does mention:

> Memory used is released only when this object is garbage collected.
>   **Closing the repository has no impact on its memory.**

However, it also states (when you want top [use it as in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14615658/6309)) that:

> This implementation builds on the DFS repository by storing all reference and object data in the local process.
>   **It is not very efficient and exists only for unit testing and small experiments**.

So don't put too large a repo in there.

Comment: Thanks,How about storing object data in remote/ local DB?

Comment: @ChetnaChaudhari the function `InMemoryRepository` is only for storing in memory, so in a local (in memory) repo by definition. This isn't for DB.

Comment: Ohh seems I missed to mention, What about writing a class which will extend DfsRepository, and that will serve from local DB. I know InMemoryRepository is just a example provided.

Comment: @ChetnaChaudhari that I wouldn't know. That DB would still need to be a compatible Git repo though.